# Une hypothèse ou non ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, pronoms-interrogatifs

Je veux dire à mon ami que je vais l'aider samedi au cas où il en aurait besoin. Il ne le sait pas maintenant.

Est-ce que je peux m'exprimer comme ça ?

> Tu me diras vendredi si tu auras eu besoin de mon aide samedi.

Ou bien est-ce une hypothèse et faut-il écrire comme ça ?

> Tu me diras vendredi si tu as besoin de mon aide samedi.

**Mise à jour**

J'aimerais clarifier un peu cette question.
Il est écrit [ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-1517.php) qu'en cas d'une hypothèse on n'utilise jamais le futur.

> Sauf cas exceptionnel, on ne trouvera jamais :
>
> Si + futur,...
>
> Si + conditionnel

Mais est-ce que cette phrase est une "hypothèse" avec laquelle il ne faut utiliser que *l'indicatif présent* ?

Comment: None of the following get many hits on Google (hence the comment), but this non-native speaker (re-hence the comment) would use a polite command (in this case where you’re offering to help) to start the proposition: “Dis-[le] moi vendredi si tu auras (vas avoir) besoin de moi/mon aide samedi” (or “… si t’auras besoin d’un coup de main samedi” if it’s a close friend). To avoid the command, you could maybe say: “T[u n]’as que me [le] dire vendredi si t[u/’]auras (vas avoir) besoin de … samedi.”

Comment: @PapaPoule  Dans l'hexagone, on préfère *Tu n'as **qu'à** me le dire...*,  la sonorité TA K L'DIRE est strictement orale et familière :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le mot « si » a deux fonctions en français. Il peut être conjonction, introduisant une condition ou une hypothèse, ou pronom interrogatif indirect pour une question oui/non.

La règle énoncée à propos des temps ne s'applique qu'au premier cas. Dans l'exemple donné, il peut s'agir d'une question indirecte. Le futur est donc possible, mais il n'y a aucune raison d'utiliser un temps composé.

> Je me demande si tu auras besoin de moi samedi.
>
> Tu me diras vendredi si tu auras besoin de mon aide samedi.

On peut aussi considérer que c'est une condition, et dans ce cas on utilise le présent, mais l'ordre préféré dans un écrit formel est le suivant 
(on notera que le pronom « le » renvoie à la condition) :

> Si tu as besoin de mon aide samedi, tu me le diras vendredi.

À l'oral d'autres variantes qui utilisent le présent plutôt que le futur sont acceptables.

> Tu me diras vendredi si tu as besoin de mon aide samedi.
>
> Tu me dis vendredi si tu as besoin de mon aide samedi.

On ne sait plus trop s'il s'agit d'interrogations indirectes ou de conditions dans ces cas-là (l'omission du « le » étant possible), mais ce n'est pas très important.

Answer (score 4):

The two options you have are:

> Tu me diras vendredi si tu as besoin de mon aide samedi.
>   *You can tell me on Friday if you need my help Saturday*
>
> Tu me diras vendredi si tu auras besoin de mon aide samedi.
>   *You can tell me on Friday if you will need my help Saturday*

The first option you suggested is expressing the "future in past", as in "*you can tell me on Friday if you would have needed my help on Saturday*", which doesn't make much sense

Comment: Do you mean “past in the future”?

Comment: *futur antérieur*: une action passée à l'avenir.

Comment: +1 For what little it’s worth, I think your use of "future in past" in scare/shudder quotes is the perfect way to describe the OP’s seemingly illogical use of the *auras eu/futur antérieur*construction to try to express an after-the-fact  determination of the need for help that could only be/will only have been/ definitely determined  on Saturday (“the future …”) on Friday (“… in the past” [vis-a-vis Saturday]).

Answer (score 0):

Il faut utiliser le futur :

> Tu me diras vendredi si tu auras besoin de mon aide samedi.